# Meaning of standard deviation

Tags: probability, statistics

If two measured values of the Hubble Constant differ by 4 standard deviations, what does this mean in plain language or in probability terms?

Answer (score 2):

It means that there is only about one chance in 16,000 that both are correct. So it is likely either that there is systematic experimental error in one or both measurements, or that the theory predicting that the two measurements should agree is wrong.

I got the 16,000 from the table [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Rules_for_normally_distributed_data).